# AI CS6 doesn't let me save

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, save

After loading a large group of vector (*.ai) files, I tried individually going through to change each one's color (they're basic, monochrome vectors).

After pasting the hex value into the object's fill-color, the object will change color - but the document name will not show a star, indicating it hasn't been saved. Furthermore I *can't* save. Furthermore, I can *exit* the document, and not only will it not ask for me to save it, but I lose my changes.

I found that I can move the object, and undo, and then it'll let me save. But this is ridiculous, especially when the graphics are thin.

**Question:** Is there another way I can change the color in one action such that it will allow me to save?

p.s. Someone plz report this bug. (Adobe Illustrator 16.0.3, 64-bit, Windows)

**EDIT:**

Exact action:

- Opened up 13 files each with one compound path (CMYK).
- Drag-select with the "Selection Tool" to easily select any shape.
- Hold shift and click the fill-color in the main toolbar at the top (by default)
- If it's not in RGB color, click on the little drop-down in the top-right corner, and select RGB.
- Select and paste into the text-box labeled "#" (Hex/Web color value)
- Press enter / click out of box. The color will apply.

At this point, I cannot save.

Comment: How are you changing colors?

Comment: by "pasting the hex values" - in the RGB color panel (shift-click fill-color) I just paste my color in the web/hex-color area.

Comment: But are you selecting something first or just arbitrarily entering a hex value with nothing selected? Clicking a swatch? Global Color? Just changing the value in the Color Panel does *nothing*.

Comment: oh, I'm selecting the object first - then pasting that value as it's fill-color

Comment: Okay, yeah.. it's a bug in 16.0.4 (you should update) Same thing happens here. Document should ask for save or be updated but is not. You could alter the color tap the left arrow, tap the right arrow, then save.

Comment: Yeah, kind of annoying. thx tho

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a bug in Illustrator 16.0.x